# Is there any particular structure needed to run nunit-console with a list of tests in a textfile?

Tags: c#, batch-file, nunit-console

I successfully ran all the tests with:

```
nunit-console bin\Debug\SeleniumAutomated.dll
```

However, when I run:

```
nunit-console /runlist:textFile.txt bin\Debug\SeleniumAutomated.dll
```

This results in 0 tests being ran. So, I am wondering if the text file itself needs any particular structure.  I have tried:

```
TestA,
TestB,
TestC
```

Also:

```
TestA
TestB
TestC
```

Also:

```
FullNameTestA
FullNameTestB
FullNameTestC
```

No luck thus far. Additionally, I would like to run this from a batch file, if that might make a difference. To qoute from http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.4 "The file 'testlist.txt' should contain the full name of each test, listed one per line."

My source for the filenames is in C#:

```
TestContext c = TestContext.CurrentContext;   
// c.Test.Name for the individual test name
// c.Test.FullName for the fullName
```

Additionally, nothing looks out of place in the text file. Testnames/fullnames are as I would expect them to be (might be wrong here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that nunit-console is picky with regard to spaces. I had a space after each line. By removing the space and using the fullname, it worked as expected.
So, for anyone else who comes across this difficulty, be sure to have no punctuation of any form. Only use the fullname - one per line.

```
FULLNAMEA
FULLNAMEB
FULLNAMEC
...
```